# Is an oracle data block similar to a txt file

Tags: database, oracle

At this link [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c03block.htm) it says that the basic unit of oracle storage is a data block.

> "One data block corresponds to a specific number of bytes of physical database space on disk."

Is it wrong to say that a data block is a like a .txt file?

Comment: The 11g [Concepts guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/logical.htm#i4894) on data blocks

Comment: A text file?! I don't see any similarities at all. Which ones do you see?

Comment: You can say that a pig is "like a peacock" if you want to but the analogy is a poor one. Likewise, saying that a data block is "like" a .txt file is a poor analogy.  As Einstein put it, "It can scarcely be denied that the supreme goal of all theory is to make the irreducible basic elements as simple and as few as possible without having to surrender the adequate representation of a single datum of experience", or as it is often summarized, "Make things as simple as possible - but not simpler". (From “On the Method of Theoretical Physics,” the Herbert Spencer Lecture, Oxford, June 10, 1933).

Answer (score 4):

A database block is a unit of *organisation*.  So it really isn't very like a .txt file.  In fact, it is more like [processed cheese](http://bmedia.fooducate.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/processed-cheese-slices.jpg).

Perhaps [a museum specimen cabinet](http://www.nhm.ac.uk/about-us/news/2007/september/images/thai-biod-cabinets-150_12359_1.jpg) is a better metaphor.  It is a storage device, with a specific location (a table) and broken up into smaller units (rows).

Although, as the data block is actually a unit of I/O we can think of it as [a train carriage](http://members.madasafish.com/~dysgraphyk/156/graphic/156_seat-layout.gif).

Ultimately, it is best to read the Concepts Guide.  Metaphors make for great poetry, but a poor one can confuse more than it enlightens.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/logical.htm#i4894).

Answer (score 0):

Off hand, I suspect that a data block has more in common with a file system block. Database files on disk are binary; they can hold anything in whatever representation the database wants. They could even hold parts of things and the rest be scattered across the file. One would almost never try to interact with their content directly. We let the database worry about what is in those files and stay out of its way, much like you would stay out of your OS's way when it's handling your disk drives.

So in short, you shouldn't care. Don't touch the content in those files unless you really, really, really, really know what you're doing. Based on the fact you're even asking this question, you don't know enough about what you're doing to mess with them.